# Why occur error java.lang.NullPointerException at surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:33) on some real device?

Tags: android, android-camera

This code is working ok on my Phone, But it occur error on some device:Galaxy Grand Prime (fortuna3g) ,Galaxy Ace Plus (GT-S7500) ,LG G4 (p1), Desire HD (ace) ,Nexus 6 (shamu) ,YUPHORIA (YUPHORIA) ,Galaxy Express (expresslte),...
to get an instance of the Camera object.

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() >= 2) {
                try {
                    c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
                    if (c == null)
                        c = Camera.open(0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    c = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    c = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    c = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
                }

            }   

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Camera did not open");
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)

        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }
```

to Create CameraPreview:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
        // preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); //Line 33 occur exception
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Permission in manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Error occur on some real device:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.noen.maihue.camerapro.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:33)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:533)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1617)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why occur error `java.lang.NullPointerException`  on some real device?
What is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this function to get Camera Instance ?

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
Camera c = null;
try {
    // attempt to get a Camera instance
    c = Camera.open(); 
    //getting current parameters
    Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters(); 
    //setting new parameters with flash
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    c.setParameters(params); 
}
catch (Exception e){
    // camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
}
// returns null if camera is unavailable
return c;
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry. error occur at row: mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); The cause is mCamera is null, function getCameraInstance can't open camera.